# Prepend to existing rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, migrate

Defining an existing rake task again appends to the original, but I'd like to *prepend* to the db:migrate task. I want to raise an error beforehand in some cases. Is there a good way to prepend to an existing rake task?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding a `db:custom` task on 'db' namespace and invoke `db:migrate` with `enhance` method

```
# add your custom code on db:custom 
namespace 'db' do
  task 'custom' do
    puts "do custom db stuff"
  end
end

# invoke db:migrate 
Rake::Task['db:migrate'].enhance [:custom]
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be better to define your own task and call db:migrate inside.

```
namespace :custom_db do
  desc 'migrate db if condition true'
  task :migrate do
    if true #your condition
      Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
    else
      #process errors
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't count on everyone who is or will be in my organization to know about `:custom_db` and remember to use it. For an individual or a small team, though, this is a good practical approach.